# method range of object _global failed in named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen the same kind of questions here but not able to solve... please help.
Hai sir presently I am in a project to transfer all excel macro did in 2003 format to 2007.The problem i am facing is method range of object _global failed
Please provide me a solution.

Please see the code... there range("Phasewt") not updating.... 
none of the named ranges in this work book are updating, everywhere its showing error 1004:
Iam using now office 2007.

```
Private Sub FormatRowsAndSum(ByVal TotRows As Integer, StartRow As Integer)
    Dim rngFormat As Range

        'adds formatting
    If TotRows > 2 Then
        Set rngFormat = Range(Cells(StartRow + 2, 2), Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 8))
        'Range("B11:H11").Select
        Range(Cells(StartRow + 1, 2), Cells(StartRow + 1, 8)).Select

        Selection.Copy
        rngFormat.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        'adds formula
        Set rngFormat = Range(Cells(StartRow + 2, 11), Cells(TotRows + StartRow, 12))
        'Range("K11:L11").Select
        Range(Cells(StartRow + 1, 11), Cells(StartRow + 1, 12)).Select

        Selection.Copy
        rngFormat.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1

    Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 2) = "TOTALS"
    Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True
    Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 2).RowHeight = 20

    Range(Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 2), Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 8)).Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With


    'writes total weight
    With Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 6)
        .Value = "=SUM(K" & StartRow & ":K" & TotRows + StartRow & ")"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    End With
    If Range("ReleaseTo") <> "STR" Then
        Range("PhaseWt") = Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 6) ' writes total wt in cover page
    End If

   'writes total cladding Area
    With Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 7)
        .Value = "=SUM(L" & StartRow & ":L" & TotRows + StartRow & ")"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    End With
    If Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 7) > 0 Then
        If Range("ReleaseTo") <> "STR" Then
            Range("PhaseArea") = Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 7) ' writes total Area in cover page
        End If
    End If

    'writes total quantity
    With Cells(TotRows + StartRow + 1, 3)
        .Value = "=SUM(C" & StartRow & ":C" & TotRows + StartRow & ")"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End With

    Range("B4").Select
End Sub
```

thanks for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "object _global failed" error shown because Excel can't find the given ranges in the workbook, so make sure you have the ranges `"ReleaseTo"`, `"PhaseWt"`, `"PhaseArea"` defined in the somewhere in the file.

**EDIT:** Try to call your code from this :

```
Sub test()
With ActiveSheet
.Range("B13").Name = "jobno"
.Range("D13").Name = "bldgno"
.Range("F13").Name = "phaseno"
.Range("D15").Name = "project"
.Range("D16").Name = "Client"
.Range("J15").Name = "location"
.Range("K12").Name = "PhaseWt"
.Range("K13").Name = "PhaseArea"
End With

Call FormatRowsAndSum(1, 10)

End Sub
```

Comment: that ranges are there thats 100% sure.. actually this range names are provided by vb2006 code... which is working fine....   With ExcelDoc.ActiveSheet
        .Range("B13").Name = "jobno"
        .Range("D13").Name = "bldgno"
        .Range("F13").Name = "phaseno"
        .Range("D15").Name = "project"
        .Range("D16").Name = "Client"
        .Range("J15").Name = "location"
        .Range("K12").Name = "PhaseWt"
        .Range("K13").Name = "PhaseArea"

Comment: What are the `TotRows` and `StartRow` values? I have run your code (Excel2010) and it is working fine. Try putting the range definitions inside the VBA code .

Comment: TotRows=1 & StartRow=10,  how to put the range defenition iside the VBA code... can you give some sample

Comment: OK then, next idea - add `.Value`to  `Range("ReleaseTo")`.

Comment: #Ref! this is the message showing in all of the cells with range names...

Comment: It's a reference error, did you delete any cells/columns/rows?

Comment: not deleted anything...:( now the program is running but any of the ranges are not updating...

Comment: I suggest you to go trough the code step by step (F8) and check if the operations it's performing are correct. Also check on a previous version of the file what cells/formulas were inserted in the currently erroneous (#Ref!)  cells.

Comment: yes will go through like that.... after that i will come back.....thank you so much dear friend for your time.....